# PHP code in Sidebar Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sidebar

I am having some issues with my dynamic php sidebar and wanted to see if anyone finds any issues with my code. Right now, the aside and other sidebar classes are closing sooner than the end of the code. I was thinking there might be something else wrong with my code that I'm not aware of.

I have a php widget plugin installed, and the below code is written in the sidebar:

```html
<div class="sidebar-container">
<button class="accordion" style="h5">Education</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . get_field('education') . '</span>'; ?></p>
</div>

<?php if( get_field('licensescertifications') ) : ?><button class="accordion">Licenses/Certifications</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . the_field('licensescertifications') . '</span>'; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if( get_field('honors') ) : ?><button class="accordion">Honors</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . the_field('honors') . '</span>'; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if( get_field('publications') ) : ?><button class="accordion">Publications</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . the_field('publications') . '</span>'; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if( get_field('affiliations') ) : ?><button class="accordion">Affiliations</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . the_field('affiliations') . '</span>'; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if( get_field('languages') ) : ?><button class="accordion">Languages</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p><?php the_field('languages'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is this WordPress?

Comment: @j08691 yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should replace position of "endif" in each block? And replace "the_field" with "get_field" in "echo" line

```
<?php if( get_field('licensescertifications') ) : ?>
<button class="accordion">Licenses/Certifications</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
    <p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . get_field('licensescertifications') . '</span>'; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or shortly:

```
<?php if( $field_data = get_field('licensescertifications') ) : ?>
<button class="accordion">Licenses/Certifications</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
    <p><?php echo '<span class="sidebar">' . $field_data . '</span>'; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, that worked! Still learning all of this. Thanks so much for your help.